# Dynamic treeTable population (openFaces) like in primefaces

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, openfaces

I have such data structure and I need to create treeTable with this.

```
Map<Manager, List<Fund>>  managerFunds
```

Is possiple to populate dynamic **treeTable** in (openfaces)?

Like it possible in **(primefaces)**

**code:**

```
 public class TreeCheckboxBean implements Serializable {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 8244744946231978985L;

            private TreeNode root;
            private TreeNode[] selectedNodes;


            public TreeCheckboxBean() {          

                Map<Manager, List<Fund>> result = new HashMap<Manager, List<Fund>>();
                result.put(new Manager(1,1,"06/31/2013"), Arrays.asList(new Fund(10, 10, "06/31/2013"), new Fund(11, 11, "06/31/2013")));
                result.put(new Manager(2,2,"06/31/2013"), Arrays.asList(new Fund(20,20,"06/31/2013"), new Fund(22,22,"06/31/2013")));
                result.put(new Manager(3,3,"06/31/2013"), Arrays.asList(new Fund(30,30,"06/31/2013"), new Fund(33,33,"06/31/2013")));

               root = new CheckboxTreeNode("root", null);        
               for(Map.Entry<Manager,List<Fund>> entry: managerFunds.entrySet()){             
                    TreeNode column = new CheckboxTreeNode(entry.getKey(),root);
                    for(Fund fund: entry.getValue()){    
                        new CheckboxTreeNode(fund, column);
                    }
                }       
            }

    // ... getters and setters
```